# URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "^*"

Tags: java, email, encode, uriencoding

i want to send an email this text

`Destination : 6W - ATLANTA WEST!@#$%^*!gemini!@#$%^*!jfds!@#$%^*!,Trailer Number : 000564,,Drop empty trailer at Plant Numbe :546,Pick up trailer at Plant Number :45, Bill Date : 25-Jan-2013,Bill Time - Eastern Time : 1,Trip Number :456,MBOL :546,Carrier :Covenant!@#$%^*!test@shaw.com!@#$%^*!transport@shaw.com!@#$%^*!test@transport.com!@#$%^*!antoalphi@gmail.com,Destination : 6W - ATLANTA WEST!@#$%^*!gemini!@#$%^*!jfds!@#$%^*!,Customer Name : 567,Cusomer Delivery Address : 657567657,General Comments :657,Warehouse Comments : 65,Carrier Comments : ,Appointment Date :25-Jan-2013,Appointment Time : 1am,Rail Only :Standard,Total Weight : 45645`

and i used this `mailContent = URLDecoder.decode(Body, "UTF-8");` decode,

but it is giving me this exception `URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "^*"`

could any one of you help me,how to solve this. I get this while sending mail.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to URL decode something that wasn't URL encoded in the first place. What's wrong with the body as it is? In other words, what happens if you just use:

```
mailContent = Body
```

(In URL encoding, the % character is used with two hexadecimal digits to encode characters that might cause problems, for example `/` would be encoded as `%2F`, as its ASCII code is 47 (decimal) or 2F (hex). In your body, `%` is followed by two characters that are not hexadecimal digits - that's how I can tell it hasn't been URL encoded, and why the decoder is erroring.)

Comment: Please elaborate and suggest me how to go about

Answer (score 2):

Simply stop calling URLDecoder.decode() and you will stop getting the error!   The string value you are passing to it is not URL encoded.

There are various forms of MIME encoding that you might want to consider, if you are sending an email with content that would not normally be allowed in an email message without encoding.  There references might be handy:

1. What is allowed in SMTP:  http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc788.html
2. Basic MIME encoding:  http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1341.html
3. Java MIME support:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html

For example, you might try:

```
String sendable = MimeUtility.encodeText(body,"UTF-8","BASE64")
```